# Bounding a series of nested integrals

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, sequences-and-series, integration

Consider the following matrix function
$$
f(t) = \cos(\omega_1t) A_1 + \cos(\omega_2t) A_2, \quad t\ge 0,
$$
where $A_1$, $A_2$ are real square matrices and $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$ positive numbers.

Now, consider the following series of nested integrals
$$
S(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{t} f(t_1)\left(\int_0^{t_1} f(t_2)\cdots \left(\int_0^{t_{n-1}} f(t_n)\, \mathrm{d}t_n\right)\cdots\mathrm{d}t_2\right)  \mathrm{d}t_1.
$$

If $\omega_1=\omega_2=\bar \omega$ then the above series converges to 
$$
 \exp\left({(A_1+A_2) \int_0^t \cos(\bar \omega \tau )\, \mathrm{d}\tau \,}\right)-I,
$$
so that, in this case, a (rather loose) upper bound to the 2-norm of $S(t)$ is
$$
\|S(t)\|\le \exp\left({\frac{2\alpha}{\bar \omega}}\right)-1,
$$
where $\alpha:=\max\{\|A_1\|,\|A_2\|\}$.

> **My question.** With reference to the case $\omega_1\ne \omega_2$ does the following upper bound hold true
>   $$
> \|S(t)\|\le \exp\left({\frac{2\alpha}{\bar \omega}}\right)-1
> $$
>   where $\bar \omega:=\min\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$? [If this is not true, is it possible to find an upper bound on $\|S(t)\|$ depending on $\bar \omega$?]

$ $

---

**A (perhaps) simplifying assumption.** From the comments of some of you, I've realized that finding such a bound is a rather difficult task for general matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$. So let us suppose that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are such that $[A_1,A_2]=V$ where $V$ is a skew-symmetric matrix and $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes the matrix commutator. *Does this assumption lead to a simplification of the problem?*

Any comment is very welcome.

Comment: If you differentiate the expression, you obtain the differential equation $\dot X(t)=f(t)X(t)$, where $X(t)=I+S(t)$. If $A_1$ and $A_2$ don't commute, there is no reason to expect solutions of this differential equation to remain bounded.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas why not? I mean, that's the question no?

Comment: Are your matrices real or complex? Skew symmetric and real or just skew symmetric?

Comment: @lcv: matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ are real and the commutator $[A_1,A_2]$ is (real and) skew-symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

I know that what I write here is rather a comment, but it is quite long, so I formulate it as an answer.

Perhaps one could look at the problem in the light of the [Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion).  It is a way of writing the transition matrix for the IVP
$$
X'(t) = A(t) X(t), \quad X(0) = I
$$
as 
$$
\exp{\Omega(t)},
$$
where $\Omega(t)$ is the sum of a series whose terms are nested integrals of nested commutators.  See [Expansions that grow on trees](https://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/notices/fea-iserles.pdf) by A. Iserles, or [The Magnus expansion and some of its applications](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physrep.2008.11.001) by S. Blanes *et al.*  In your case, the matrix function $A(\cdot)$ is periodic (when $\omega_1/\omega_2$ is rational), or quasi-periodic.  Regarding the former, see [Floquet theory: exponential perturbative treatment](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physrep.2008.11.001) by F. Casas *et al.*

Magnus expansions are notoriously difficult to deal with, but perhaps for your choice of matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ the formulas for $\Omega(t)$ simplify (let's hope so!).  Then you can have some estimate.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Suppose that $[A_1,A_2]=S$, where $S$ is skew-symmetric (here square brackets denote commutator). Do you think this assumption could be helpful?

Comment: Yes, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there holds $\langle e^{tS}x, e^{tS}x \rangle' = \langle Se^{tS}x, e^{tS}x \rangle + \langle e^{tS}x, Se^{tS}x \rangle = \langle e^{tS}x, (S - S) e^{tS}x \rangle = 0$, that is, $\lVert e^{tS} \rVert = 1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So, do you mean that, from the fact $\|e^{tS}\|=1$, a bound on (the norm of) the Magnus expansion can be found? (I don't see how...)

Comment: No, I don't know exactly: just thinking aloud.

Comment: Is $f(t)$ anti-hermitian? That would help

Comment: @user539887 the Peano-Baker series is precisely the OP’s series. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @lcv You're right, that's the same.  I removed my comment.